# Why does netstat report lesser number of open ports than lsof

Tags: linux, networking, netstat, lsof

I have storm running on 2 machines.

Each machine runs nimbus process (fancy for master process) and worker processes.

And I wanted to see the communication between them - what ports are open and how they connect to each other.

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep -w 10669
tcp        0      0 :::6700       :::*            LISTEN      10669/java          
udp        0      0 :::42405      :::*                        10669/java          


$ lsof -i :6700
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    10669 storm   25u  IPv6  57830      0t0  TCP host1:50778->host2:6700 (ESTABLISHED)
java    10669 storm   26u  IPv6  57831      0t0  TCP host1:6700->host2:57339 (ESTABLISHED)
java    10669 storm   29u  IPv6  57843      0t0  TCP host1:6700->host1:50847 (ESTABLISHED)
java    10669 storm   53u  IPv6  57811      0t0  TCP *:6700 (LISTEN)
java    10681 storm   53u  IPv6  57841      0t0  TCP host1:50780->host2:6700 (ESTABLISHED)
java    10681 storm   54u  IPv6  57842      0t0  TCP host1:50847->host1:6700 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What I dont understand from the above output is that why netstat does not show port 50778 being open in the process with PID=10669 where as `lsof` clearly shows that the same process has an established connection as `host1:50778->host2:6700`

Comment: Because you're comparing apples and oranges. Try `netstat -tulpn | grep -w 6700`.

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | grep -w 6700` returned only one row for 6700. I still don't see port 50778. If its obvious to you, please explain the same in an answer. Others might not have the same experience or knowledge as you and would benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat -l` limits the results to listening sockets, and prevents the display of sockets in other states.

Try this instead:

```
netstat -anp | egrep :6700
```